# MySQL & PHP decimal precision wrong

Tags: php, mysql, decimal, precision

24151.40 - 31891.10 = -7739.699999999997

I grab these two numbers from a MySQL table with the type as decimal(14,2)
24151.40
31891.10
It is saved exactly as stated above and it echos exactly like that in PHP. But the minute I subtract the second value from the first value, I get a number -7739.699999999997 instead of -7,739.7. Why the extra precision? And where is it coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [an article I wrote for Authorize.Net](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Precision-Math-with-PHP/ba-p/8368):

One plus one equals two, right? How about .2 plus 1.4 times 10? That equals 16, right? Not if you're doing the math with PHP (or most other programming languages):

```
echo floor((0.2 + 1.4) * 10); // Should be 16. But it's 15!
```

This is due to how floating point numbers are handled internally. They are represented with a fixed number of decimal places and can result in numbers that do not add up quite like you expect. Internally our .2 plus 1.4 times 10 example computes to roughly 15.9999999998 or so. This kind of math is fine when working with numbers that do not have to be precise like percentages. But when working with money precision matters as a penny or a dollar missing here or there adds up quickly and no one likes being on the short end of any missing money.

**The BC Math Solution**

Fortunately PHP offers the [BC Math extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) which is "for arbitrary precision mathematics PHP offers the Binary Calculator which supports numbers of any size and precision, represented as strings." In other words, you can do precise math with monetary values using this extension. The [BC Math extension contains function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)s that allow you to perform the most common operations with precision including [addition](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php), [subtraction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcsub.php), [multiplication](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php), and [division](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php).

**A Better Example**

Here's the same example as above but using the bcadd() function to do the math for us. It takes three parameters. The first two are the values we wish to add and the third is the number of decimal places we wish to be precise to. Since we're working with money we'll set the precision to be two decimal palces.

```
echo floor(bcadd('0.2', '1.4', 2) * 10); // It's 16 like we would expect it to be.
```

Comment: Is there no better way to do ecommerce math? BC looks like it will get messy.

Comment: It's not messy really. Just some functions that ensure precision math. They're not complicated to use IMHO.

Comment: It's not that it is complicated, just hate the fact I have to add this function every time I need to handle money.

Comment: For example adding an array of money values would no longer be easy as array_sum

Comment: Ideally it would be that easy.

Comment: @anderson so why not write functions similar to the ones avaialble in php using the BC functionality.  array_bc_sum for example.  For loop through the array adding the digits together, and there you have it a new function that works like the old function but with precision.

Comment: @JohnConde how come we dont have to do the bcmul function for the 1.6 * 10

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have a decimal type like MySQL does, it uses floats; and floats are notorious for being inaccurate.

To cure this, look into `number_format`, e.g.:

```
echo number_format(24151.40 - 31891.10, 2, '.', '');
```

For more accurate number manipulation, you could also look at the math extensions of PHP:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php

Comment: wow really? is there anyway to store decimal types into the MySQL table that won't require me to use number_format every time I am using a value selected from MySQL?

Comment: @Anderson You can retrieve from MySQL without having to do anything; it's only needed after you have manipulated (add / subtract) the value  and need to write it back into the database. In fact, when it comes out of MySQL it's still a string :)

Comment: so this would occur even if i were to convert the string into a number?

Comment: @Anderson Yes, it would convert from string to float in your case. But, again, that's only if you intend to manipulate the value.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with general float / double precision rates, which scientifically relates to 1.FRACTAL * 2^exponential power. Being that there's a prefix of 1, there's technically no such thing as zero, and the closest value you can obtain to 0 is 1.0 * 2 ^ -127 which is .000000[127 0s]00001

By rounding off your answer to a certain precision, the round factor will give you a more precise answer

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round