# How to update MySQL column = column-number

Tags: php, sql

I have this mysql columns:

```
points_on | points_off
    0          1.36
```

And this SQL command:

```
UPDATE table SET points_off = points_off-{$cash}, points_on = points_on+{$cash} WHERE ...
```

$cash = "1.36"

If I run this, the table update wrong like this:

```
points_on | points_off
   1.36      0.0000000143051
```

How to update this correctly?

I need to move **$cash** number from points_off to points_on.

Comment: How come your `points_on` column value changes whilst you are updating the `points_off` column. That's weird O.o

Comment: sorry, i update the SQL command.. second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the MySQL field type `float` or `double`?

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html, the problem is that `float` values are stored approximated.

You should use `decimal`, defined as `decimal(M,D)`, where `M` is the maximum number of digits in the number (e.g., for 0.00 to 9.99, `M = 3`), and `D` is the number of digits after the point (e.g., for 0.00 to 9.99, `D = 2`).

I performed the same operations you tried, got the same problem, and fixed it with `decimal`.

Beware though that `decimal` fields require much more storage space than `float`.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @cash float

set @cash=1.36
update  [dbo].[stkkk] set [pts_on]=[pts_on]+@cash

update  [dbo].[stkkk] set [pts_off]=[pts_off]-@cash
```

Comment: Im amateur, this is SQL command? `mysql_query("declare ...")`?

Comment: hmm..nope this is from sql-server !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this stems from how PHP internally represents numbers. From what I can tell, PHP stores numbers as a floating point decimal, which may generate strange output such as yours.

I recommend reading the following StackOverflow articles:

- [PHP - Floating Number Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision)
- [MySQL & PHP decimal precision wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452744/mysql-php-decimal-precision-wrong)

Not sure if it would work 100%, but you might want to try implementing some code to ensure your doing math accurate to two decimal places instead of letting PHP decide. The referenced articles may be of some help.